# Dragging element and mouseout event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have an div container that contains an element that can be dragged (with jQueryUI).

```
<div id="container" style="width:150px;height:100px;">
    <div id="child">dragme</div>
</div>
```

I add a border when hovering over the container element. I remove the border, when the mouse leaves the container.

```
$('#container').mouseover(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).css('border', '5px solid red');
});
$('#container').mouseout(function () {
    $(this).css('border', '0px');
});

$('#child').draggable({});
```

The problem: When I drag the child element, the border is not removed. The drag does not trigger the mouseout event. Is there another event that I could use to remove the border from the container when the mouse leaves it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use events.

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "dragstop", function( event, ui ) {
      $('#container').css('border', '1px solid black');
} );
```

API Documentation:
http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable

Comment: surely the border should be 0px on dragstop? if she wants it removed?

Comment: The important part is to use the event. You can add border, images or that you like, it is not relevant to the topic. OP needs to listen on drag end event and the code is this. The OP doesn't accept the answer yet, but it is the correct answer, sure

Comment: And how would I know if the child element was dragged across the container's border? Because only if the mouse is moved outside the container should the border be removed.

Comment: The function pass two arguments, the event and the UI object. You can play with UI object to know if is inside of the container